# Aggregate raster using function with multiple conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to aggregate a raster using a specialized function with multiple conditions. I'm getting caught up in the syntax of "if else" and wondering if someone can help.

Here is what I'm trying to do in agg.fun:

1. set all NA values to -9999
2. values below or equal to 100, or 10 or greater, take the mean
3. values greater than 100, if they are 30% or more of aggregated cells, then set values to -9999, or if less than, then set values to the mean weighted by the fraction missing (-9999)
4. anything else is -9999

   ```
   agg.fun <- function(x) {
       if (max(x) == NA) {
       return(-9999)
       } else if (max(x) <= 100 && max(x) > 10) {
       return(mean(x))
       } else if (max(x) <= 10)) {
       return(0)
       } else if (max(x) > 100) {
           cloud.count <- length(which(x==250))
           cloud.per <- cloud.count/(ncol(x)*nrow(x))
               if (cloud.per >= 0.3) {
               return(-9999)
               } else (cloud.per < 0.3) {
               return(mean(x) + cloud.count * 0.5)
              }
       } else {
       return(-9999)
       }
   }


   r <- raster(matrix(rep(c(1:100),100),100,100))

   #randomly set some values to 250
   r[sampleRandom(r,1000,cells=TRUE)[,'cell']] <- 250

   #randomly set some values to 200  
   r[sampleRandom(r,100,cells=TRUE)[,'cell']] <- 200

   #set some values in raster to NA
   r[r%in%c(200,201,211,225,237,239,254,255)] <- NA

   #attempt to run aggregate (doesn't work right now)
   r.agg <- aggregate(r, fact=3, fun=agg.fun, expand=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this :

```
agg.fun <- function(x,...) { ## you should add ... for na.rm,and other extra parameters
  x[is.na(x)] <- -9999
  if (all(x  <= 100 & x > 10))return(mean(x))
  else{
    len_100= sum(x>100)
    len_missing = sum(x==-9999)
    if(len_100 < 0.3*length(x))
      return(mean(x)+ 0.5*len_missing)
  }
  return(-9999)
}
```

1. Set all missing values to -9999
2. if all values in [10,100] return mean values
3. if number of values > 100 is less then third of total values return the mean values weigthed by missing values
4. return -9999 in all other cases.